# Toast message isn't working in angular project

Tags: angular, primeng, toast

I added the toast module following the instructions from https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/toast . In my ts file for the component I added MessageService as a provider, and I had a messageService variable and I had a showSuccess message that would be called once a link/button was pressed. It worked with growl, but I need to use toast because growl is depreciated.

```
showSuccess() {
    this.messages = this.toast
    this.messageService.add({key: 'myKey1', severity: 'success', summary: 'Sample', detail: 'sample'});
}

<a (click)="showSuccess();"
<p-toast key="myKey1" position="top-right"></p-toast>
```

The above code worked above if I had growl.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an error message? I was able to get a popup to work using this:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [MessageService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  showSuccess() {
    this.messageService.add({ key: 'myKey1', severity: 'success', summary: 'Service Message', detail: 'Via MessageService' });
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<p-toast key="myKey1" position="top-right"></p-toast>
<p-button (click)="showSuccess()" label="ClickMe"></p-button>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ToastModule } from 'primeng/toast';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule, ToastModule, ButtonModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: could you post a screenshot of what it looks like?

Comment: Here's a StackBlitz template I modified with your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-nd2qnk

Answer (score 0):

Did you import ToastModule into your application?

```
import {ToastModule} from 'primeng/toast';
```